# Will unique indexes ignore fields that don't exist?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB index:

```
Reservation.index(
    {
        source: 1,
        accountID: 1, // <-- This is the only required field
        confirmationCode_1: 1,
        confirmationCode_2: 1,
        confirmationCode_3: 1
    },
    {name: "Unique_reservation_index_1", unique: true}
);
```

Here are some sample entries I have in the database and I want to make sure that duplicates can't be made:

```
[
    {
        source: "A",
        accountID: "AAA",
        confirmationCode_1: "ABC"
    },
    {
        source: "B",
        accountID: "BBB",
        confirmationCode_1: "ABC"
        confirmationCode_2: "DEF"
    },
    {
        source: "C",
        accountID: "CCC",
        confirmationCode_3: "GHI"
    }
]
```

Sometimes I have `confirmationCode_1` set and not `confirmationCode_2` other times I both `confirmationCode_1` and `confirmationCode_2` set.  Other times I have `confirmationCode_3` set.

I want MongoDB to allow me to have the following doc (missing the `confirmationCode_2` and `confirmationCode_3` fields). Will it let me with the above index?

```
    {
        source: "A",
        accountID: "123",
        confirmationCode_1: "ABC"
    }
```

Will it prevent me from adding two similar docs with `confirmationCode_2` not defined or will that be considered the same?  For example, if it does allow the above doc, will this be prevented?

```
    {
        source: "A",
        accountID: "AAA",
        confirmationCode_1: "ABC_2"
    }
```

If I don't supply the `confirmationCode_2` field, does it set the `confirmationCode_2` field to `null`?

If I change the unique index to include `sparse: true`, how will it act differently?

```
Reservation.index(
    {
        source: 1,
        accountID: 1, // <-- This is the only required field
        confirmationCode_1: 1,
        confirmationCode_2: 1
    },
    {name: "Unique_reservation_index_1", unique: true, sparse: true}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

From MongoDB document on [unique Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-indexes),

> A unique index ensures that the indexed fields do not store duplicate values

undefined / empty / null field is allowed as long as you do not have the same tuple of values of the fields in the compound index.

Below is my actual testing result:
[image]

[image]

You can observe that the document is successfully added under the unique index.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you add it twice?

Comment: no, it's expected behaviour of the unique index to prevent duplication

Comment: ok, I see.  What if you change `unique: true` to `unique: true, sparse: true`?  Will it let you add it then?

Answer (score 1):

*Will unique indexes ignore fields that don't exist?*

No, the index will store a null value for this field, MongoDB will enforce uniqueness on the [combination](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-constraint-across-separate-documents) of the index key values.

```
//You have this docuemt on you MongoDB
{
    source: "A",
    accountID: "123",
    confirmationCode_1: "ABC"
}

//You try to insert the next document, note the missing "accountID" field
//Even though "source" and "confirmationCode_1"
//This operation SUCCESS because
//MongoDB will enforce uniqueness on the "combination" of the index key values
{
    source: "A",
    confirmationCode_1: "ABC"
}


//You try to insert the next document
//The operation FAIL to insert the document
//because of the violation of the unique constraint 
//on the combination of key values
{
    source: "A",
    accountID: "123",
    confirmationCode_1: "ABC"
}
```

*What if you change `unique: true` to `unique: true, sparse: true` ?*

> An index that is both sparse and unique prevents collection from
> having documents with duplicate values for a field but allows multiple
> documents that omit the key.